# Are discrete random variables, with same domain and uniform probability, always independent?

Tags: distributions, self-study, random-variable, independence, uniform-distribution

If $X$ and $Y$ are discrete random variables, both with domain $\{-1,0,1\}$, with uniform probability, does this imply they are independent? What would be the expected value $\mathbb{E}(XY)$ and probability like $\mathbb{P}(XY=1)$ or $\mathbb{P}(XY=-1)$ in this case?

Comment: actually if the domain of a random variable is finite then the random variable is discrete right? i remember there was some kind of rule like if $\Omega$ is finite or countable than $X: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ is discrete. but the converse isn't true like a constant random variable on any uncountable $\Omega$

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is simple to construct an example where both variables are marginally uniformly distributed, but they are not independent.  The simplest example is to take $X \sim \text{U} \{ -1,0,1 \}$ and let $Y=X$.  In this case both of the variables have a uniform distribution, but they are perfectly correlated.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. How can we calculate P(XY=1) or E(XY) in such cases?

Comment: You would just take an appropriate sum over the joint distribution.  For example, in the case in my answer we have $\mathbb{E}(XY) = \tfrac{1}{3} \cdot (-1)^2 + \tfrac{1}{3} \cdot 0^2 + \tfrac{1}{3} \cdot 1^2 = \tfrac{1}{3} + 0 + \tfrac{1}{3} = \tfrac{2}{3}$.

Comment: And if it’s too much to have the random variables be equal, let $Y=-X$.

Comment: Okay, thanks again Ben! How about the correlation between any two variables that follow these properties? Is it always going to be -1, 1, or 0?

Comment: No. Counterexamples are easily constructed

Comment: For example, take mixture of (a) uniform over the four values in $\{-1,0\}^2$ and (b) an atom at $(1,1)$, with mixing weights $\frac23$ and $\frac13$ respectively. The marginals are as required but the correlation is none of the three suggested values

Comment: FWIW, it's even possible to have $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be uniformly distributed over the same support, such that any two of them are *pairwise* independent, but all three of them are not independent. One simple construction is to let $X$ and $Y$ be independent and uniformly distributed over $\{-1, 1\}$ and let $Z = XY$. A similar trick can work over $\{-1,0,1\}$ too, but requires a slightly more complicated formula for $Z$ (such as choosing $Z$ as the unique solution of the modular congruence $Z \equiv X + Y \pmod 3$ in $\{-1,0,1\}$).

Answer (score 5):

You can say $X$ and $Y$ each have mean $0$ and variance $\frac23$ and in general

- Their covariance is equal to $\mathbb E[XY]$ here and can be any value between $-\frac23$ and $+\frac23$ so their correlation can be any value between $-1$ and $+1$
- $\mathbb P[XY=+1]$ and $\mathbb P[XY=-1]$ can each be between $0$ and $\frac23$
- $\mathbb P[XY=0]$ can be between $\frac13$ and $\frac23$

If they are independent then

- Their covariance is equal to $\mathbb E[XY]$ and is $0$
- $\mathbb P[XY=+1]=\mathbb P[XY=-1] =\frac29$
- $\mathbb P[XY=0] =\frac59$

It is possible for them to have covariance and $\mathbb E[XY]=0$ without them being independent, for example if $(0,0)$ has probability $\frac13$ while $(+1,+1)$, $(+1,-1)$, $(-1,+1)$, $(-1,-1)$ each have probability $\frac16$, in which case $\mathbb P[XY=+1]=\mathbb P[XY=-1] =\frac13$  and also $\mathbb P[XY=0] =\frac13$

Answer (score 4):

No, suppose you have $X$ as you described and for $Y$ you flip a coin and in 0.5 probability it takes the value of $X$ otherwise you uniformly sample from $\{-1,0,1\}$.

The marginal probabilities will be uniform yet they are obviously dependent. Short simulation below.

```
x    <- sample(c(-1, 0, 1), 100000, TRUE)
coin <- rbinom(100000, 1, 0.5)
y    <- coin * sample(c(-1, 0, 1), 100000, TRUE) + (1 - coin) * x

     
> cor(x, y)
[1] 0.4986911
```

[image]

You can see that $X$ any $Y$ are dependent and have the same marginal uniform distribution.

Comment: Thanks Kozolovska! That's a very nice example. Can we calculate P(XY=1) or E(XY) in this case (when they're not independent) ?

Comment: @John: Clearly $\mathrm P(XY=1)$ can take any value from $0$ (when $Y=-X$) up to $\frac23$ (when $Y = X$); just consider mixtures of those two distributions (i.e. let $Y = -X$ with probability $0 ≤ p ≤ 1$ and $Y = X$ otherwise). It's not hard to prove that $\frac23$ is an upper limit, either; just consider the marginal probability that $X=0$. I'll leave calculating the range of $\mathbb E(XY)$ as an exercise, but similar reasoning works there too.